# Finding vertices of a undirected graph that are connected in second graph

Tags: graph, subset, vertices, undirected-graph

If I have an undirected graph, `G = (V, E)`, and I want to find the subset `S` of vertices in `G` such that all the vertices in `S` have at least `n` connections to other vertices in `S`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, this task sounds similar to the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). Which might suggest your task will be NP-hard as well.

At second thought, it's actually much simpler and here's an algorithm:

1. remove all v of degree less than n
2. repeat (1) on the
   restricted G until it's empty or all remaining vertices have degree
   n or more
3. the remaining vertices are your subset S